# There is no T-invariant subspace $U$ such that $\mathbb{R}^{3} = W\oplus U$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve the following problem problem?

PROBLEM. Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $\beta$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that
$$ \left[ T \right]_{\beta} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$
If $W = \operatorname{ker}(T -2I)$, proof that there is no T-invariant subspace $U$ such that $\mathbb{R}^{3} = W\oplus U$.

Comment: What are your efforts for solving this problem?

Comment: I calculated the eigenvalues and the respective eigenspaces. Both eigenspaces are of dimension 1, therefore the matrix is not diagonalizable. Could this information about the eigenspaces help me solve it?

Comment: Yes, but what's more important is that $(T-2I)e_1 = e_2$ and $(T-2I)e_2 = 0$, where $e_j$ denotes the $j$-th vector of the basis $\beta$.